# C# Substitute DispatcherObject From .Net Framework 4.5 to .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.1

I want to substitute DispatcherObject From .Net Framework 4.5 to .Net Core 2.1.

Can I use other class to achieve this?

My code in .Net Framework 4.5 as reference is below:

```
// If the subscriber is a DispatcherObject and different thread.
DispatcherObject dispatcherObject = handler.Target as DispatcherObject;

if (dispatcherObject != null && !dispatcherObject.CheckAccess())
{
    // Invoke handler in the target dispatcher's thread... 
    // asynchronously for better responsiveness.
    dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, handler, this, e);
}
else
{
    // Execute handler as is.
    handler(this, e);
}
```

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Assuming that your code is WPF one, what do you want to substitute in .NET Core, which doesn't contain WPF? Could you describe task with more details?

Comment: @Dennis HI, because DispatcherObject in .Net Core 2.1 is not support. :(

Comment: Maybe I should remove it. .Net Core no UI thread.